# Collecting condensed air

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm trying to funnel steam through a tube to eventually collect the condensation. Should I make the tube as wide as possible? or would narrower be better? assuming the length and material are the same. I get that I want to dissipate heat so should I maximize surface area with a wide tube?

Thanks

Comment: There is no simple right answer to this. What pressure for the steam? How much steam per second? How are you going to cool the pipe? How long a pipe?

Answer (score 0):

Smaller tubes have a higher surface area in proportion to their cross section, and dissapate more heat.
A longer tube is better.

Answer (score 0):

In order to dissipate the most heat in the fastest manner, you would need a long, narrow tube. It should be narrow because objects with a high surface are to volume ratio lose more heat, but you want the steam to go through a lot of pipe so that it has longer to cool down - which is why you want a long pipe